# How to run a class enum through a switch in C++

Tags: c++, enums

I have two Classes that are working parallel with each other. The first is Room the second is Ship. Within ship, I have to use the Room class to check if something is valid. I am running a switch statement because I do different things with different entries. The problem is that the defining variable that goes into the switch statement from Room is an enum, and the compiler doesn't like that.

This is what I have

```
bool Ship::checkRoom ( const Room& theRoom )
{
     switch (theRoom.getType)
```

For reference, this is where "getType" is called:

```
inline RoomType getType() const { return mType; };
```

Comment: You forgot your parentheses. `theRoom.getType()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass class enum values to a switch statement. But you need to *call* the function:

```
switch (theRoom.getType())
```

Here's a working example:

```
enum class FOO { A, B };

struct Foo
{
  FOO getFoo() const { return FOO::A; }
};

int main()
{
  Foo f;
  switch (f.getFoo())
  {
    case FOO::A:
    case FOO::B:
      break;
    default:
      break;
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a function to the `switch`, not an `enum`. So, you should call the function to use its return value in the switch.

Long story short - you have missed parenthesis.

```
switch (theRoom.getType)
```

needs to be

```
// --------------------vv
switch (theRoom.getType())
```

Answer (score 0):

You **can** switch on enums in C++ as they are integral types. In fact, it's useful as you can then use the enumerator values in the case labels which makes your program clearer.

What you have is essentially a typo: `theRoom.getType` is the address of the function, with a data type that you're not supposed to switch on.

You need to use `switch (theRoom.getType())`. Note the brackets.